# React Router Dom V6 loaders fire when router is created

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to implement routing in to my application with `react-router-dom` V6 using the new  `createBrowserRouter` function and `RouterProvider` component.

When trying to implement a `loader` (see routes `themeLoader`), the loader is always fired as soon as the `router` is created (see App.tsx).

Granted this only happens on the `theme` route as it should, but as it is firing at such an early stage it is being triggered before the authentication has started let alone completed and the queries it calls require an authenticate user.

Is it possible to delay the `loader` until authentication has completed?
I have tried `shouldRevalidate` but this does not prevent the `loader` from firing the first time.

```
// PrivateRoute.tsx
function PrivateRoute(Props: PrivateRouteProps) {
  console.log('PrivateRoute!');
  // Auth logic here
  if (isAuthenticating) return <div>Authenticating...</div>;
  return !isUnauthorised ? <Outlet /> : <div>{'Unauthorised Access'}</div>;
}
```

```
// Theme.tsx
export async function themeLoader({ params }: LoaderProps) {
  console.log('themeLoader!');
  const query = store.dispatch(getTheme(params.theme));
  const { data: theme } = await query;
  query.unsubscribe();

  if (theme === undefined)
    throw new Response('Theme Not Found', { status: 404 });
  return theme;
}
```

```
// Routes
const themeRoute = {
  path: 'themes/:theme',
  element: <ThemePage />,
  loader: themeLoader
};

const parentRoute = {
  path: '/',
  element: <PrivateRoute authorisedRoles={MemberRoles} />,
  errorElement: <RouteBoundary />,
  children: [themeRoute]
};
```

```
// App.tsx
const router = createBrowserRouter([parentRoute]);
// themeLoader fires at this point...

function App() {
  console.log('App!');
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}
```

```
// Console Output
themeLoader!
App!
RouteBoundary!
```

```
// Expected Output
App!
PrivateRoute!
themeLoader!
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you cant.

Loaders are called in parallel, so they cannot block each other or provide each other data.

https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/9188#issuecomment-1248180434

Comment: OP's issue is the same as mine where the loader on the path is running before the component has even been mounted. Even if I remove the RouterProvider, it is still firing. Is this by design or some other issue? I am not worried about data in child routes, but am querying why loaders fire when the createBrowserRouter is executed. It means that anything that needs to come from the store aren't ready before the route fires.

Comment: @JarrodMcGuire Apparently its by design